# FATAL EXCEPTION: main ----- when i click on button (unfortunaly gsctutoandroi has stopped)

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edtMsg;
    private Button btnEnvoyer;
    private String resultat=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtMsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMsg);
        btnEnvoyer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnvoyer);
    }

    public void envoyerMessage(View v){

        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/Envoi/applicationEnvoi.php");
        String msg=edtMsg.getText().toString();

            if(msg.length()>0) {
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> donnees = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);  
                    donnees.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(donnees));
                    client.execute(post);
                    edtMsg.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Message Envoyé",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this,"Ce champs ne peut etre vide",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: please help me, the application stopped i when i click on the button

Comment: @user2932964 you need to post your logcat in your question no try editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `thread` or `Asynctask` for network related operation.

```
  client.execute(post);// post should be executed on a thread.
```

Since you are doing it on main thread you are probably getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` (for post honeycomb versions).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html